# Javascript - How to prevent blocking during nested For loops?

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a set of nested For loops in my script (vanilla javascript, no jquery) that could go on for quite a while (30+ seconds). During this time, the browser is obviously unresponsive and the DOM isn't updating because the loop is blocking - just as one would expect.

Inside the nested For loops, I'm calling another function and generating a SVG circle with the parameters being passed and then adding the circles to an svg element and returning to the loop.

**Question: what strategy can be used to update the DOM and actually show some of the SVG circles being created?**

There are a lot of questions on S/O asking for similar solutions, but most of the examples use setTimeout(function, 0) and although I have tried using this, the DOM doesn't update probably because I'm not sure which function I should set the Timeout for?

I've also found some examples of webworkers, but can't quite wrap my head around how I could actually use those in this project.

Using this basic example - could someone show me how I can update the DOM while the loop is processing?

```html
<button onclick="randomCircles()">
  make circles
</button>
<svg 
  id="cont" version="1.1" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  x="0" y="0" viewBox="0, 0, 900, 600">
  <style>svg { background-color: black;}</style>
</svg>
```

```
<script>
    function randomCircles(){
        var x_end = 900;
        var y_end = 675;
        for(x=0; x<=x_end; x += 5){
            for(y=0; y<=y_end; y += 5){
                var new_circle = Math.random();
                         drawCircle(x,y,new_circle);
            }
        }
    }

  function drawCircle(x,y,circle_radius){
    var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var container = document.getElementById('cont');
    var circle = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'circle');
    var circle_to_draw = circle_radius * 2;
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', x);
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', y);
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', circle_to_draw);
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'style', 'fill: white; stroke: none;' );
    container.appendChild(circle);

    return;
  }
</script>
```

Very basic example (fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wx67uyzv/2/)

**Here is an updated fiddle with the solution, thanks to Joel!**

https://jsfiddle.net/198znrc0/

Comment: you should first pass parameters x and y to `drawCircle`, then within this function call `setTimeout(function() { ... }, 0)` where `...` is the current content of `drawCircle` (`var svgns = etc.`)

Comment: But with all these `setTimeout`s you would just delay the DOM manipulation to the next event loop iteration so that's probably not going to help that much. With `setInterval` as suggestion by @michael-bianconi you can control (to some extent) the "framerate" and eventually limit it, for instance to a fixed number of circles drawn per frame, in order to avoid freezing effects.

Comment: Joel - that was what I needed! Thank so much.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

```
// sample values
var loopSpeed = 25;  // How often the window will refresh, in milliseconds
var loopEnd = 75;
var loopStart = 5;
var loopIncrement = 5;


var i = loopStart;
var intervalId = setInterval(() => {

    if (i === loopEnd) {
      // wrap up
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      return;
    }

    // do loop stuff
    i += loopIncrement;

}, loopSpeed);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer - where would that go in the code example I posted? Do I wrap the nested loops inside of the code you posted?

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your code into multiple chunks which you can run without blocking browser for long time. Here is simple example of how it can be done, tried to keep it as close as possible to your original code. Basically you draw certain number of circles `circlesCount` per cycle and then use `setTimeout` to let browser update DOM.

```js
  
  function randomCircles() {
    var x_end = 900;
    var y_end = 675;
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var circlesCount = 20;
    function randomCirclesIteration() {
      var drawnCircles = 0;
      for(; x<=x_end; x += 5){
        for(; y<=y_end; y += 5){
          new_circle = Math.random();
          drawCircle(x, y, new_circle);
          drawnCircles++;
          if (drawnCircles == circlesCount) {
            setTimeout(randomCirclesIteration, 0);
            return;
          }
        }
        y = 0;
      }
    }
    randomCirclesIteration();
  }
  
  
  
  function drawCircle(x, y, circle_radius){
   var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
  var container = document.getElementById('cont');
    var circle = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'circle');
    var new_circle = (circle_radius * 2).toFixed(2);
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', x);
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', y);
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', parseFloat(new_circle));
    circle.setAttributeNS(null, 'style', 'fill: white; stroke: none;' );
    container.appendChild(circle);
  }
```